# Why order by relevance is using filesort on a fulltext search?

Tags: mysql, indexing, full-text-search

I have a table with columns `id,title,price` with PK on id and fulltext search index on `title`

In this table i store selling goods.
I want to do a fulltext search on title and to order my results by relevance, but i noticed that this query will use a filesort to order by relevance.

My table have like 1.000.000 rows and i need to perform this search in less then 2 seconds.

```
SELECT *, 
  MATCH(title) AGAINST ('search terms' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
  AS relevance 
  FROM `goods`
  WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST ('search terms' IN BOOLEAN MODE) order by relevance desc,price desc;
```

I do something wrong here? how to perform an fast search, less then 2 seconds by relevance order? I don't want to use other third party apps.

Thanks!

Comment: How fast does the query run without the `order by`?  How many rows are being returned?  How long is the search actually taking?

Comment: @GordonLinoff if i search for `iphone` i have like 14.960 results and take about 10-15 seconds.

Comment: . . That is a really long time for sorting 15k records.  Could the problem be returning the results to the app?  How long does it take without the `order by`?

Comment: I forgot to mention, i also order by price, i have also column price and i order desc. editing question now